# Angular 6 material warning in console

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui-bootstrap

In My Angular Application i have installed "angular-bootstrap-md": "^6.3.0",

GIT repository: https://github.com/fareed543/Angular-6-App

When I run the application its giving error in console.

ng serve

**in terminal its showing :**

```
    ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/fesm5/angular-bootstrap-md.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\project6\node_modules\angular-bootstrap-md\fesm5\angular-bootstrap-md.js'
```

**in console**

```
./node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/fesm5/angular-bootstrap-md.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\project6\node_modules\angular-bootstrap-md\fesm5\angular-bootstrap-md.js'
```

Here is my package.json file.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^6.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^15.0.2",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^6.3.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ng-drag-drop": "^5.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure angular-bootstrap-md @ 8.2.0 is compatible with angular 6?

Comment: Can you tell me the compatable version with angular 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its an issue with package angular-bootstrap-md, I downgraded it with 6.1.1.

```
"angular-bootstrap-md": "^6.1.1",
```

its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

In the installation steps of the library ([HERE](https://github.com/mdbootstrap/Angular-Bootstrap-with-Material-Design#how-to-install-mdb-via-npm)) they also say you have to manually install some dependencies such as `chart.js` and `hammerjs`.

To make your project work, you need to run the following command:

`npm install angular-bootstrap-md@^6.3.0 chart.js@^2.5.0 hammerjs@^2.0.8`